# accessing private videos on Vimeo, through Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I used https://player.vimeo.com/video/id/config, to get the private videos on Vimeo account. But now this api is deprecated, is there a way to get the private videos on Vimeo. I tried authorizing to Vimeo getting the access token and using https://api.vimeo.com/videos/id api with authorization token, but I keep getting "Video not found" response. I am using this on iOS app, so I can't have whitelisted websites for a video to be displayed, the video is going to be showed in the app.

tried to use https://api.vimeo.com/videos/id api but getting "Video not found" response.

Answer (score 0):

To access private videos, you need to ensure your access token is authenticated to you and has `private` scope. See below for what this looks like in the token dashboard.

[image: vimeo developer site example]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have both the "private" scope and also "video files" scope to  access the playback and download links of the video.